# Can plugins like WP Pro Quiz and WP Rocket be responsible for slowing down LearnDash?

Tags: wordpress, performance, learndash

We have LearnDash installed on our website and have been experiencing very slow speeds. We are trying to ascertain if there are any plugins or scripts that are responsible for slowing our site down. When using the browser Inspector tool, we have found reference to a plugin / script for wp_pro_quiz_check_lock (which seems related to a plugin or include called WP Pro Quiz). This script is called on every page of the website. Does anybody have any experience with resolving slow LearnDash speeds, also any knowledge of wp_pro_quiz script causing issues?

We have scanned all files for wp_pro_quiz plugin and only found reference to wp-content/plugins/sfwd-lms/includes/lib/wp-pro-quiz - could this be slowing the site down. Also reference to wp-rocket caching plugin.

Comment: I also had issues with LearnDash performance. For you, wp_pro_quiz_check_lock loads on every page or just LearnDash pages? For me, it loads only in some of the quiz pages (surprisely there is a quizz where it does not load) but not on lessons and not on any other page of the site.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned in the basic information about the WP Pro Quiz plugin, this plugin can be freed from the problem of always running on the server and WordPress by changing and correctly configuring the settings of this plugin, and it will increase the quality and speed of your website.

Comment: Thank you, however we have ascertained that we aren't using the WP Pro Quiz plugin. There seems to be a call that runs on every page of our website which relates to the LearnDash plugin. That call is running from the file /wp-pro-quiz/js/wpProQuiz_front.js. Action: 'wp_pro_quiz_check_lock'. Could this be slowing it down and if so can it be disabled?